# Magento Get Different options to select from Options.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a admin back-end options section/module to control few things like upload slider images, site background, banners etc. That is simple cause it just requires xml code in system.xml. I want to add different drop-downs, radio buttons, multiple select. I have the following code in Options.php Its giving me options to select one, two or three for every drop-down, radio or multi select. What I have to define here to get different options? not just one, two and Three.

```
    <?php
    class Options_CustomConfig_Model_Options
    {
      /**
       * Provide available options as a value/label array
       *
       * @return array
       */
      public function toOptionArray()
      {
        return array(
          array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'One'),
          array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
          array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three')                   
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so this is what needs to be done to get more options:
I created another folder in Model called Optiontwo and inside Option.php.
Class for options.php have to have folded in it like this:
class CustomConfig_Model_**Optiontwo**_Options.
And then in system.xml for source_model have to be declared like this:
customconfig/Optiontwo_options

Thanks to [Adrsh Khatri](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/9860/adarsh-khatri) for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly try this:

```
<?php
    class Options_CustomConfig_Model_Options
    {
      /**
       * Provide available options as a value/label array
       *
       * @return array
       */
      public function toOptionArray()
      {
        return array(
          array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'One'),
          array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'Two'),
          array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'Three'),

          array('value'=>4, 'label'=>'your_name'),
          array('value'=>5, 'label'=>'another_your_name')
          // you can keep adding these lines.
        );
      }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

**update**

Right, then add following in your `system.xml` file where needed:

```
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>moduleName/path_to_your_file_option</source_model>
```

and now create a file called `option.php` (you can give your own name) in `model/path_to_your_file` and add following:

```
<?php
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Path_To_Your_File_Option
{
    /**
   * Provide available options as a value/label array
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function toOptionArray()
  {
    return array(
      array('value'=>1, 'label'=>'A'),
      array('value'=>2, 'label'=>'B'),
      array('value'=>3, 'label'=>'C')                   
    );
   }
}
```

**PS** File path is very important.

Comment: No, what i mean is to have more options not just one two three in all. For example if i want 3 different drop-downs lets say one has options like 10, 100, 1000. Another drop-down with different options like A, B, C. And another like Him, Her, Them. Understand?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: No, I have all this already. Are you trying to say i should create another module with another Options.php?

Comment: You have to create diff files for those where you want different values in same module.

Comment: Well, That is another question. How?

Comment: Create a new directory (any_name) in your `Model` folder and create a new file called `Option.php` in that folder. Then go to your `etc/system.xml` and edit the `<source_model>` section pointing to your new file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27503/discussion-between-mysticalghoul-and-adarsh-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

For the a-hole who down voted.

[image]

in source_model
customconfig/Optiontwo_options